# unorderable types:type() > int

Tags: python, types, int

I am having trouble with my code. I keep getting errors all over this. Right now I am getting unorderable types error. Basically I need my program to accept a seat limit and then make sure how many tickets were sold is inside that limit. Then I just need to calculate the income generated by the ticket sales. I am quite new to python, so any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

```
aLimit=200

bLimit=500

cLimit=100

aPrice=20

bPrice=15

cPrice=10

ticketSold=int

def Main():

    ticketSold=int(input("How many tickets were sold? "))
    getTickets(aLimit)
    total=calcIncome(ticketSold,aPrice)
    print("The theater generated this much money "+str(total))

def getTickets(limit):

        ticketsValid(ticketSold,limit)
    return ticketSold


def ticketsValid(ticketSold,limit):

    while (ticketSold>limit or ticketSold<0):
        print ("ERROR: There must be tickets less than"+str(limit)+"and more than 0")
        return False

    return True



def calcIncome(ticketSold,price):  
    return ticketSold*price


Main()
```

Comment: What kind of error did you get? In your answer's program or in parser of your program?

Comment: `ticketSold=int` makes `ticketSold` an alias for the builtin type `int`. This is unlikely to ever be useful. If you're trying to declare the variable to have that type, you can't do that in Python.

Answer (score 2):

`ticketSold` isn't a number, it's the type `int`. In Python, types are objects too! You can assign them just like any other object.

You're probably expecting the `input` in `Main` to replace the value, but it's actually creating a new value internal to the function. You need to use `global ticketSold` inside `Main` to get the results you expect.

I would think about rearchitecting this to use return values instead of global variables.

Comment: Initially, but in `Main`, it gets re-assigned.  If that assignment ISN'T changing `ticketSold`, you'll need to explain why.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I was busy typing that explanation just as you made your comment.

Comment: How would I do this with return values instead? This is my first coding class and I am super confused, but I enjoy learning

Comment: Using a global here is fine for such a small program. Parameter passing has its place, but you have five other global names, and Python globals are safely module-level anyway.

Comment: I think @MarkRansom misspoke: instead of relying on global variables, if you need to get a value into a function, you should pass it as a parameter, as you do elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks guys. Alright now I have it all put in the program, but even though i have the TicketSold defined as global, I am still getting an error saying global type not defined.

Comment: @kojiro: "Doing it wrong" isn't the answer, even when it is a small program.

Comment: @Matthias But we disagree that globals are always wrong. FUD is always wrong, but globals (particularly Pythons globals, which are not really global at all, but module-level) have their place.

Comment: Anyway, refactoring this entire thing to use parameter passing would require fixing the weird `while-that-is-really-an-if`, most likely removing `getTickets` entirely and raising an exception in `ticketsValid` because it's not clear how the program should proceed if `ticketsValid` returns `False`. But that would be a cumbersome and offtopic bunch of code review for the question at hand.

Comment: @kojiro: If there is no other solution `global` might be used. I can agree to that.

Comment: There's always another solution.

Comment: A solution in search of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with variable scope. Yes, you have a name 'ticketSold' that is in the global scope, but it is not the same as the variable with the same name in the `Main` scope. You must declare this variable global to use it globally.

```
def Main():
  global ticketSold
  ticketSold=int(input("How many tickets were sold? "))
  …
```

If you don't do this, your global `ticketSold` will remain what you assigned it as. Namely, a `type` object of `int`.

Comment: I suspect some people think it reasonable to down vote answers competing with their own without comment.

Comment: @MattH I don't think that's what happened in this case. I don't see any deleted answers and I don't suspect you or Mark of it. But I do suspect that there are ideologues who would downvote an answer containing the word *global* because they read globals are bad on the Internet, but don't have the argument chops to actually make the case in a comment.